# Manga where a guy goes into a game he's playing. He's nicknamed "lucky boy" by white mages

Tags: story-identification, manga

The story of this manga starts with a guy I believe going into a game he played. The game became a real world and in this world if you die in the dungeon you will respawn in the guild at a black door.

The main character has a super powerful staff that was somehow was brought with him. He sells it and everyone starts to call him '*lucky boy*'. In this world white mages which are main character is usually only hide and sacrifice themselves to revive other party members in raids. While he has a different way of play. Him and his party of two other do really well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[Live Dungeon](https://anilist.co/manga/110999/Live-Dungeon/)* (AKA. *ライブダンジョン!*)

White mages? Check. "Lucky boy"? Check.

> An old MMORPG called Live Dungeon. Before the service was terminated, Kyotani Tsutomu made full use of 5 notebook PCs to clear the game and was invited to a different world. And then, Tsutomu was speechless when he saw a live relay of a dungeon capture in the different world. They bulldozed through without any thought of strategy. The misfortune of getting the healer position. Tsutomu reinstated the White Mage that had always been his favorite in games and aimed to conquer the dungeon to find the key to his escape from the different world.

Comment: This person was looking for it too; https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/jg8k2m/looking_for_manga/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: that is it thank you